# Como alterar a largura das colunas na listagem do Admin no Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-templates, django-1.8

Como faço para especificar a largura para as colunas que são exibidas na listagem do Admin, mais precisamente as que especifico em list_display no admin.py. Pesquisando encontrei questão parecida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309788/how-to-fix-set-column-width-in-a-django-modeladmin-change-list-table-when-a-list%20aqui), onde cheguei a conclusão de que devo extender o arquivo change_list.html. Então criei um arquivo de mesmo nome no diretório templates da minha aplicação com o seguinte trecho, onde 'price' seria a minha coluna:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <style type="text/css">
    #price { width: 100px; }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Contudo nada aconteceu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente colocar no style:

```css
th.column-price{width:100px;}
```